# How to get response ajax on the vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

My code is like this :

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click="addFavoriteStore($event)">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;Favorite
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props:['idStore'],
        mounted(){
            this.checkFavoriteStore()
        }, 
        methods:{
            addFavoriteStore(event){
                alert('tost');
                event.target.disabled = true
                const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}
                this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteStore', payload)
                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(true)
                }, 1500);
            },
            checkFavoriteStore(){
                const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}
                this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload)
                setTimeout(function () {
                   location.reload(true)
                }, 1500); 
                //get response here  
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When the script executed, it will call checkFavoriteStore method first

By checkFavoriteStore method, it will call action on the vuex store

And the results will return the response

How to I get the response?

**UPDATE**

My action on the vuex store like this :

```
import { set } from 'vue'
import favorite from '../../api/favorite'
import * as types from '../mutation-types'

// actions
const actions = {
    checkFavoriteStore ({ dispatch,commit,state },payload)
    {
        favorite.checkFavorite(payload,
            data => {
                commit(types.CHECK_FAVORITE_SUCCESS)
            },
            errors => {
                commit(types.CHECK_FAVORITE_FAILURE)
                console.log(errors)
            }
        )
    }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
    [types.CHECK_FAVORITE_SUCCESS] (state){
        state.addStatus = 'success'
    },
    [types.CHECK_FAVORITE_FAILURE] (state){
        state.addStatus = 'failure'
    }
}

export default {
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

And the api like this :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Resource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.use(Resource)

export default {

    // api check favorite exist or not
    checkFavorite (favorite, cb, ecb = null ) {
        Vue.http.post(window.Laravel.baseUrl+'/member/store/favorite/check-favorite', favorite)
            .then(
            (resp) => cb(resp.data),
            (resp) => ecb(resp.data)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us your code related to AJAX ?

Comment: have a look at my answer here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/how-to-get-response-ajax-on-the-vuejs-2

Comment: @Belmin Bedak, This : this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload). It will call action on the vuex store

Comment: what he's asking is for the code within the store that calls and returns the response from this call this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload)

Comment: as mentioned on laracast you have it refreshing the page i think after 1.5 seconds so any response would be missed????

Comment: @Simon Davies, Seems that it does not require reloading. So basically I just need a response only. If the response returns true, then it is button unfavorite. Vice versa

Answer (score 2):

if your returning a result then assign the call to a variable so tyr:

```
  var res = this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload);
```

then you can get access to the response via the var `res`.  I believe the events will return it back to you

MORE query:

just a little question on this.

If your getting the store ID and passing this to the component as a prop.  So surely you could also pass in another prop that tells if the store has already been liked?  So getting this data via the db call to the view, thus saving having to do a check after its loaded, so something like:

```
  <favorite-button :storeid="23" :favorited="true"></favorite-button>
```

So using the favorited property to change the button accordingly?, so need for the `checkFavoriteStore` call and saving time on additional http request etc

Don't know your code or what's its doing etc but just a thought??

EDIT AFTER ADDITION INFO ADDED

OK so can you change your http request to say:

```
Vue.$http.post(window.Laravel.baseUrl+'/member/store/favorite/check-favorite', favorite)
  .then((response) => {
      console.log('success')
      console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  }, (response) => {
       console.log('success');
        console.log(response);
    return response;
  });
```

i have added console.logs so we can see whats happing.  let's see if this helps?

also try adding a return in front of, as it needs to return to its original caller

```
 return favorite.checkFavorite(payload,
        data => {
            commit(types.CHECK_FAVORITE_SUCCESS)
        },
        errors => {
            commit(types.CHECK_FAVORITE_FAILURE)
            console.log(errors)
        }
    )
```

Also a comment, do you need all this complexity for just this simply check, i don't know the rest of your code and construction, but as suggested passing in the state of the button as a prop (as above) and just handle the isFavorited call within the compnent itself, so no need to use a store fo this simple request??

EDIT 2:

if you need to return another wahy with promise try::

```
Vue.$http.post(window.Laravel.baseUrl+'/member/store/favorite/check-favorite', favorite)
  .then((response) => {
      console.log('success')
      resolve(response.data);// replace the return with resolve?
  }, (response) => {
       console.log('success');
        console.log(response);
    reject(response.data);// replace the return with reject?
  });
```

Might be the issue??

Comment: I do this : var res = this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload);console.log(res);. The result : https://postimg.org/image/grd6mqe4n/. Should the response display `exist` or `no_exist`

Comment: can add the store call so the code that is used once called `checkFavoriteStore`, so we can see the code your using to return, as this is a Promise so need to see how its constructed

Comment: i have updated my answer with a request.  PS try Axios instead of Vue resource as this will soon be discontinued/not supported i beleive

Comment: You use get. Should post. So I replaced the post such as these: `Vue.http.post (window.Laravel.baseUrl + '/ member / store / favorite / check-favorite', favorite)`. The result like this : https://postimg.org/image/kzceokuer/

Comment: so your reponse is 'exsist' so its working need now to return that to the inital request or what need the resposne???

Comment: Why when I do this : var res = this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload);console.log(res);. The result : https://postimg.org/image/grd6mqe4n/. Should the response display exist. So how to keep the response displays `exist`. I need this because I want to create the conditions for displaying the button unfavorite

Comment: have you added a RETURN to this as i have `return favorite.checkFavorite`, also if you still get the promise, you might need to use `resolve()` instead of return in the Vue.http.post and a `reject()` in the error, added it as well above so ou can see?

Comment: Yes, I using return. But, It's the same. How to using resolve() anda reject(). I never using it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134132/discussion-between-moses-toh-and-simon-davies).

Comment: Needs a `return` before `Vue.$http...` too

Comment: @Phil, Great. It works. Thanks. I do this : `var res = this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload);console.log(res);`. The result this : https://postimg.org/image/b8q50fxz3/. How to get PromiseValue? I try : `console.log(res.promise.PromiseValue);`. But, it's not working

Comment: @mosestoh You need to wait till it's resolved, ie `res.then(val => ...)`

Comment: @mosestoh https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises

Comment: @Phil. Done. I try this : res.then((res) => console.log(res));

Answer (score 1):

below is a solution that does not require a store, just a thought might be handy:

PHP Page:

```
    <favorite-button 
        :storeid="{{$storeid}}" 
        :favorited="{{$isFavorited}}"
        :url="{{route('check-favorite')}}"
    ></favorite-button>

    <script>
        (function(){
            import favoriteButton from 'favorite-button';
            new Vue({
                el : '#app',
                components : {
                    favoriteButton
                }
            });
        })();
    </script>
```

Then the component

```
    <style lang="sass">
        .heart {
            color: grey;
            &.is-favorited {
                color: red;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click.prevent="udateFavorited($event)">
            <span class="heart" :class="{'is-favorited' : this.favorited }">&heart;</span>&nbsp;<span :text="{this.favoriteText}"></span>
        </button>
    </template>
    <script>
        import axios from 'axios';
        export default{
            props : {
                storeid : {
                    type: Number,
                    required : true,
                    default : () => {}
                },
                favorited : {
                    type: Boolean,
                    required : false,
                    default : false
                },
                url : {
                    type: String,
                    required : true
                }
            },
            computed : {
                favoriteText : function(){
                    return (this.favorited) ? 'Unfavorite' : 'Favorite';
                }
            },
            methods:{
                updateFavorited(event){
                    //-- so update the db so if fasle update to true else if true = false
                    axios.post(this.url, this.storeid)
                        .then(response => {
                            //-- all ok update the visual button
                            this.favorited = response.data.favorited
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log('error');
                            console.log(error);
                            this.favorited = response.data.favorited
                    });

                }
            }
        }


    </script>
```

So basically on initial loading the page, it passes the storeid, and whether the store is or not already favorited, as well as the url action on click event

Then when a user clicks the user clicks the button it will update the DB and then the text and the colour of the heart, depending on the result

Just another idea/solution to consider if having issues??