# How to add condition in method vue.js 2?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, laravel-5.3, vuejs2

My code is like this :

```
<template>
    <a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-block btn-success" @click="addFavoriteStore($event)">
        <span class="fa fa-heart"></span>&nbsp;<label id="favoriteId">{{ store_id == $store->id ? 'Un-Favorite' : 'Favorite' }}</label>
    </a>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props:['idStore'],
        mounted(){
            this.checkFavoriteStore()
        }, 
        methods:{
            addFavoriteStore(event){
                var label = $('#favoriteId');
                var text = label.text();

                event.target.disabled = true
                const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}

                if(text == "Favorite") {
                    this.$store.dispatch('addFavoriteStore', payload)
                }
                else {
                    this.$store.dispatch('deleteFavoriteStore', payload)                        
                }

                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(true)
                }, 1500);
            },
            checkFavoriteStore(){
                const payload= {id_store: this.idStore}
                this.$store.dispatch('checkFavoriteStore', payload)
                // this is response. return store_id
            }
        },
        data: {
            store_id: ''
        }
    }
</script>
```

I make the conditions as described above

You can look at the method addFavoriteStore

Whether that step is correct?

And how to determine it was favorite label or not to create conditions?

**UPDATE**

In console exist error like this :

```
[Vue warn]: The "data" option should be a function that returns a per-instance value in component definitions.
```

Comment: what errors you gettign or trying, can u explain a little more?  Also instead `event.target.disabled = true` why not add the `prevent` call on the click method `@click.prevent=""` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html :-)

Comment: Your question is not very clear, so please consider about improving it.What you want to achieve ? Where is the actual problem ?

Comment: @Simon Davies, I had update my question

Comment: @Belmin Bedak, I had update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As error says, when you are dealing with the components, data should be defined as function that return an object - so:

```
data() {
  return {
   store_id: ''
  }
}
```

Comment: When I click button favorite, in console exist error like this : https://postimg.org/image/intx89aer/

Comment: It's error related to the backend - basically you are not sending correct data to the enpoint or as error says unathorized - so if you have any kind of auth on your app make sure you are logged in

Comment: In Firefox browser, no error. but there is an error in the browser chrome

Comment: Okay question is, are you logged in into Chrome browser ?

Comment: Not yet. I am sorry. Thanks for you help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134223/discussion-between-moses-toh-and-belmin-bedak).

Comment: Seems I need you help again. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904428/how-to-update-data-on-a-page-without-refreshing-on-the-vue-js

Answer (score 1):

your data should be set as:

```
  data() {
     return {
       store_id: ''
     }
  }
```

As its a component? Try this?

Comment: That's not correct example - data is still object, it should be function.

Comment: @Simon Davies, When I click button favorite, in console exist error like this : https://postimg.org/image/intx89aer/

Comment: that mean your trying to access that route that is protected by the 'auth middleware, so you will need to either send the auth headers with the call ect, what your using axios/ajax etc to call it

Comment: @Simon Davies, In Firefox browser, no error. but there is an error in the browser chrome

Comment: is it posting and working in both or does not work in both but only reports in chrome, if does not work try posting a new issue etc

Comment: @Simon Davies. Done. I have not logged in chrome :) Thanks for you help

Comment: @Simon Davies, Seems I need your help again. My other question no one has replied. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41881933/how-to-get-response-ajax-on-the-vue-js-2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134222/discussion-between-moses-toh-and-simon-davies).

Comment: @Simon Davies, Seems I need you help again. Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904428/how-to-update-data-on-a-page-without-refreshing-on-the-vue-js